# Default setting for dimmable light bulb on a non-dimmable lamp

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I have a brand new dimmable light bulb, but a floor lamp that doesn't have a dimmer. Is the light bulb going to be working on full power out of the box i.e. it's not going to be dimmed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be on at full brightness.

A dimmable lamp is just that, dimm**able**, but it needs a dimmer to do so.